# Create color with emmet abbreviation

Tags: html, css, vim, emmet

My vim's version is 8.2,vim-emmet version is 0.86.
How to write the abbreviation for the CSS as below?

```
border: 1px solid #dcd2ba;
```

In the manual it says that:

[css abbreviation](https://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/)

> For example, bd5#0s expands to border: 5px #000 solid: the # sign separates color from 5 and since s (alias to solid) is not a hexadecimal character, it can be used without - value separator.

Why in my vim,`bd5#0s` expand nothing?
And a strange expansion happened in my vim:

```
bd1s
```

expanded into

```
border-break: close;
```

and

```
bd1 s
```

expanded into

```
border: 1px solid #000;
```

BUT

```
bd2 s
```

expanded into

```
box-shadow: inset hoff voff blur spread rgb(0, 0, 0);
```

instead of

```
border: 2px solid #000;
```

Which configuration is wrong for my emmet? and How to check out and fix it?

Comment: are you using it on css file or sass file?

Comment: I am sure i am using it on my css file, MaanooAk had a same conclusion as me, you can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look in the source code, I don't think... it's bug free.

The actual rule for the border statement:

```
"bd+": "border:${1:1px} ${2:solid} ${3:#000};",
```

which would suggest that the correct order is with color at the end, but in my testing I couldn't make it to work. Also I tried adding a alias for `s=solid`, which it is stated that exists, but I could not find it in the source code.

Also some other example of the doc, do not work at the moment.

I conclude, in my opinion, it is just broken. (I would suggest you to add your own snippet.)

Answer (score 2):

The emmet documentation describes how to add hex colors. See https://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/

> bd5#0s expands to border: 5px #000 solid: the # sign separates color from 5 and since s (alias to solid) is not a hexadecimal character, it can be used without - value separator.

So in your case use `bd1#dcd2bas`

Comment: It is a normal logic conclusion infered from the manual ,have a try in your vim then?